# How to broascast message to client not subcribe for a topic in Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I want to use **Action Cable** (Rails 5) to create a chat app.

When the client signs in to the app, I send the message to subscribe for the channel. The channel will stream for connection based on `current_user` 's `room_id`. 
When the user sends a message it will be sent to all who subscribed for the channel
That 's normal flow of action cable.

Here is my channel:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
   current_user.chatrooms.each do |chatroom|
       stream_from "room_#{chatroom.id}"
   end
 end
end
```

But I wonder when the client sends the message to the new one who is not in the room. The streaming was not created. How can the other receive the message and keep the conversation move on?

Answer (score 0):

For a user who is sending the message, you can create a callback in your message model that broadcasts to your channel when a message is created. I assume you created correct associations. i.e Rooms `has_many` messages. Message in turn `belongs_to` `Room` and `User`
Something like this:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
    after_create :broadcast_to_room
    .......
    private
    def broadcast_to_room
        @room = self.room
        RoomChannel.broadcast_to(@room, message: self)
    end
    .........
end
```

So whenever a message is created, it is broadcasted to the room the message belongs to.
Your RoomChannel can be like this:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
        room = Room.find(params[:id])
        stream_for room
    end
end
```

Now in the from facing page of the room, you should have a function that subscribes to listen for incoming messages. So when a message comes in, your listener picks up the message and displays it.
I wrote a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lordkiz/2a950c788b3993c5a84df26f1772f7b7) on how you can use actioncable in a client (in react-native). In your client you create a socket that listens for incoming messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, LordKiz.                                                                      I am using Android as my client.                                                                      As my query is at the time the channel broadcast the message. Cause this is the first time two user start to chat together, the room has just created (room_id not existed in the database) and it is not streaming on the server. That mean client didn't subcribe for that stream and cannot receive the incoming message.

Comment: Exactly. If client is not subscribed, it is impossible to receive incoming messages. You should create a room with an id in your database when two users start a chat. And stream to that room.

Comment: So in this case, client needs to send the request to re-subscribe channel, right? or do something to stream to that room on the server? I still don't know how to hande this.

Comment: Yea. Everytime client opens that room, create a socket that subscribes to the channel.